# How to solve the number of game frame decreased when we use Particles / Additive texture mapping?

Tags: frame, textures, unity-game-engine, alpha, particles

The game engine:unity3D

The number of game frame decreased significantly, when we use Particles / Additive texture mapping and the tga format picture with Plane model which has the channel and alpha in the scene.

PS: We use the version: 3.5.0 and the Ellipsoid Particle Emitter of the Legacy Particles with ios target platform.

Answer (score 1):

To improve performance try to:

- Use a "mobile" shader (mobile/particles/additive)
- decrease the time live of your particles
- Reduce the particle texture resolution
- Reduce the max particles emitted